# wifi connection problem in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: wireless, cpu

Trying to solve a wifi problem. Wifi cuts out every few minutes. Also seems to pause when working. (Separately, but perhaps related, Ubuntu freezes when using wifi.)

In running "top" I saw that when wifi is connected, there was a kworker process using 100% CPU every few minutes. kworker 6:1. When I turn wifi off, the kworker does not consume much CPU. Also, ethernet connection works fine.

The problem began in Ubuntu 20.04. I am now running the new Ubuntu 21.04 (5.11.0.37) on a Dell Inspiron 5515 with 16 gb ram, 5000 AMD processor, and 1 TB. Using Intel wi-fi 6 ax200 network card. Should be good.

Any advice on how to determine what the issue is?

For the record, I have used Mint on older machine with no issue, but I am definitely a Linux/Ubuntu newbie.

Comment: Check your system firmware is up to date, and if it's not, update it.

Comment: Liam Proven, thanks. Checked Ubuntu firmware and it was fine. Also went ahead and made some Dell BIOS updates, but the problem is still there.

Comment: It was the system firmware I meant, not in Ubuntu, but there's no harm. Other troubleshooting steps you can try: test it with a totally different distro booted from USB. Something unrelated like openSUSE or Fedora. Also, see if it works stably in Windows, but that probably means a reinstall. :-(

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.